# Timber rendering unwanted <p> and <br> tags in Gutenberg blocks

Tags: wordpress, twig, advanced-custom-fields, timber, wordpress-gutenberg

For some reason, my twig templates are rendering empty `<p>` tags and unwanted `<br>` tags in my ACF Gutenberg blocks.

This is causing me to have to remove code indentation and formatting in order to remove these unwanted elements. For example, I have to change:

```
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

to:
`</div></div></div>`

in order to remove empty paragraphs.

Is there any way to retain code formatting while preventing these tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be an issue at this point. You can use the following workaround

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
add_filter( 'the_content', function ($content) {
    if (has_blocks()) {
        return $content;
    }

    return wpautop($content);
});
```

[github issue](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/12530) - [workaround](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/12530#issuecomment-443736873)

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have fixed the issue. Hopefully Gutenberg will get up to par here soon.